# managed bean constructor called twice

Tags: jsf-2

This is maybe no big problem but i am trying to optimize my app.
It is jee6 application with jsf2.0 framework, primefaces2.1 and glassfish3.1.

I have situation where on click on commandLink I have to do smth on the servers side and then redirect to the other page with some get parameters. 
And I solved it by using p:commandLink with nested f:param. Action returns string wihch is navigation outcome to the other page defined in faces-context with redirect and include-view-params="true". 
And everything works fine. BUT, when I looked in trace I saw that managed bean's constructor is called twice after rendering destination page (page two). So managed bean loads some data from database twice which i would like to awoid

Code:

page1:

```
...
<p:commandLink value="Go to page2" action="#{bean1.doSmthBefore}">
<f:param name="param1" value="1"/>
</p:commandLink>
...
```

bean1:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean1{
    public void doSmthBefore(){
        ....
        return "page2";
    }
}
```

page2:

```
...
<f:metadata>
<f:viewParam name="param1" value="#{bean2.param1}"/>
</f:metadata>
...
```

bean2:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean2{
   String param1;
   public Bean2(){
      sout("Constructor") //<-trace
   }
   //geters seters...
}
```

Comment: Where in page2 is your *bean2* referenced from? Maybe you are fetching some kind of *id* attribute from *bean2* and therefore it is constructed twice?